# Tables wont be close to each other

Tags: html, css

I am writing simple html & css for website. And i have one problem. I have this login form (i know it will wont work, its just html and css code, i am not coding php into it and making this kind of stuff)

```
<table style="padding-top:5px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="200"     height="34">
<tr>

<td width="81" height="32"><input class="login-reg" type="button" value="Registrácia"></td>
<td width="37"><input class="login-ok" type="button" value=""></td>
<td width="82"><input class="login-reset" type="button" value="Reset hesla"></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

and css

```
.login-ok{
    background-image: url("images/ok.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#00a651;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:35px;
    width:35px;
}
.login-reg{
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    height:25px
    padding:0px;
}
.login-reset{
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    border-top-right-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    height:25px
}
```

And i just want to make it together. Like on this screen (i know style is different but i need to make it looks like "one element" or how i can describe it) [screen](http://prntscr.com/4t8413)

jsfidle if someone wants [jsf example](http://jsfiddle.net/yuhy8m1a/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot some ; and did a bit of mess with widths. This is working: http://jsbin.com/besebazerobe/1/

```
.login-ok{
    background-image: url("images/ok.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#00a651;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:35px;
    width:100%;
}
.login-reg{
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    border-top-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    height:25px;
    width:100%;
}
.login-reset{
    background-color: #3a3a3a;
    border-top-right-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color: #fff;
    height:25px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple remove margin from inputs:

```
.login-reg, .login-reset{
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yuhy8m1a/18/)

Comment: I dont know why but on jsfiddle it works well, but in my chrome it wont work. http://prntscr.com/4t86ub

Answer (score 0):

Just remove unnecessary margins and collapse table borders, here you are:

```
input {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yuhy8m1a/12/)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Add width to `.login-reg` and `.login-reset`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42s7yagb/)

Comment: A short explanation of why this is the solution wouldn't harm. See [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one with css only : http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/7e5uo15u/

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #101010;
  /* outer shadows  (note the rgba is red, green, blue, alpha) */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
  /* rounded corners */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px 0px 0px 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
  border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 7px;
  /* gradients */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #101010), color-stop(15%, #101010), color-stop(100%, grey));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #101010 0%, #101010 55%, #grey 130%);
}
#center {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #000000;
  /* rounded corners */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #00ff00;
  /* gradients */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, green), color-stop(15%, green), color-stop(100%, grey));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, green 0%, green 55%, #grey 130%);
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 125px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  /* outer shadows  (note the rgba is red, green, blue, alpha) */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(23, 69, 88, .5);
  /* rounded corners */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px 0px 0px 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
  border-radius: 0px 7px 7px 0px;
  color: white;
  /* gradients */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #101010), color-stop(15%, #101010), color-stop(100%, grey));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #101010 0%, #101010 55%, #grey 130%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">Registracia</div>
  <div id="center">✔</div>
  <div id="right">Reset Hesla</div>
</div>
```

[image]
Hope it helps!